# having problem with NZEC runtime error and decimal

Tags: python, runtime

In a codechef problem im getting this runtime error NZEC .

```
T = input();
for i in T:
    n = float(input())
    loss = 0
    for j in n:
        p = float(input())
        q = float(input())
        d = float(input())
        newp = (p + p*d*0.01)
        finalp = (newp - newp*d*0.01)
        loss = float(loss + (p-finalp)*q)        
    print(str.format('{0:.11f}', loss))
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm new to python programming. 
Also can anyone tell me how can i get a total of 11 digits in output.
using `print(str.format('{0:.11f}', loss))` statement i get only 11 digits after decimal but i want that total no of digits before and after decimal be 11.

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nzec-error-python/. NZEC simply means your program had an error while on some online platforms such as codechef. Did you get any other error messages? I can see at least one error that should be reported. the `for j in n` line should give error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.